# Event Id:8003 The Master Browser Error

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-event-log

I receive the following error on Windows Server 2008 the last a few days.

```
event id 8003

The master browser has received a server announcement from the 
computer computername      that believes that it is the master 
browser for the domain on transport 
NetBT_Tcpip_{DE9119B3-7798-4ACB-9D0A-7CBFBBB471E6}.
The master browser is stopping or an election is being forced.
```

Has anyone encountered this?

cheers,

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd investigate the computer named in the event for failing network connectivity or bad network drivers. This has occurred, in my experience, when a single computer or portion of a network is being temporarily disconnected from the rest of the network repeatedly. The isolated computer or segments performs a browser election while disconnected, then causes these events to be generated when it subsequently becomes reconnected and the master browser announcements are "seen" by the real master browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, the computer with the latest OS has a higher priority in a browser elections with servers the highest priority (Master Browser verses backup browsers). I believe their is one backup browser for every 32 clients on a lan. When one of the backup browsers are turned off, gracefully, it notifies the master browser and a broadcast election is forced on the lan for a new one. Each node on the lan sees this election then broadcast their challenge with their OS bit weight in the challenge packet.The node with the latest OS will win the election and send out 3 notices to all that he is the new backup browser. If the backup browser is turned off un-gracefully (crashed) the device that discovers the backup browser is no longer there initiates an election.