# Mrxsmb (Event 8003) brings down the Network

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, eventviewer

There a domain with Windows SBS 2003 as the DC. At regular intervals, I am faced with the Mrxsmb (Event 8003) error which brings down the network. We have to other Windows SBS 2003 servers on the network, one of which was causing this. I have disabled the Computer Browser service on both of these.

Now, the Windows XP and the Windows 7 clients in that Domain show up with this error in the DC's log at different times. **Every single time**, it brings down my network.

Is there anything I am missing out here?

As a temporary solution, I have manually "disabled" (*because when it is stopped and the startup option is "manual", it still gives me this error*) the Computer Browser service in all the client PCs - is that the right solution or is there any other better solution?

On checking, as suggested in [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/238107/event-id8003-the-master-browser-error), the network hasn't been disconnected at any given point in time, however, the PCs are restarted in some cases at certain points in time.

Would appreciate it if you could suggest some sort of permanent solution to this...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "Brings down the network" meaning, what, exactly?  And on the topic of networks, what do your switches and routers have to say?  Is it just Windows clients having a problem, or is your network gear getting slammed too?

Comment: @HopelessN00b - "Brings down the Network" - the whole network hangs, the users' PCs hang with no access to any PC/Network resources. All the switches are unmanaged switches and they need to be restarted as well for the users to be able to access anything.

Comment: Well that's definitely not normal, and I'm not even sure how an election for the master browser service would do such a thing.  I suspect that one of your unmanaged switches is flaking out and failing temporarily to cause this issue in the first place - and when it tries to reconnect it causes the master browser election you see as event 8003, but hangs or causes a broadcast storm as well, which is actually what causes the network to "go down."  I'd get wireshark on some of my computers to investigate what's happening on the network next time it "goes down."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this issue (though I'm pretty sure that there is a better way to do it). I manually disabled all the Master Browser services in all the Client PCs (both XP and Windows 7) and 2 Server machines (MS Server 2003) which were part of the said network. Once they were all disabled and only the Domain Controller's Master Browser service was enabled, this issue was not faced again.

@HopelessN00b - Thanks a lot for your inputs.